# What is the best way to save fields details of sensor's registers?

Tags: c

I'm interfacing a sensor to BeagleBone Black via SPI. I can read and write registers successfully. What I want to do now is to be able to access each individual field (e.g., X1, X3) in the register to read from or to write to.

I also can do this but with a long boring way. I don this by defining an enum that contains the names of the fields in the registers. Then I declared a struct that contains three pieces of information: address of register of the field, first bit of the field and the last bit. Then, I defined an array of structs with the number of fields. Finally, I have to initialize these three values (address, 1st bit and last bit) for each individual field.

Following is a sample of my code:

```
enum {X1, X2, X3,     // Fields of register in address 0
      X4, X5,         // Register in address 1
      X6, X7          // Register in address 2
     } FIELD;

typedef struct
{
      int address;
      int first_bit;
      int last_bit;
} FIELDS;

FIELDS fields[3];

fields[X1] = (FIELDS) {.address = 0x00, .first_bit = ..., .last_bit = ...}
...
```

As I said, this way works, but the problem is that I have a big number of fields in the sensor (around 60). In the future, the sensor may change and I'll have to change the names and the related information of the fields.

The current method is time-consuming, tedious, error-prone and not easily adaptable to different sensors.

I think there should be a smarter, more adaptable and less-error-prone way to do this?
Could you please suggest any better way to achieve my goal?

[image: Sample of sensor's registers]

Comment: How does any of this make sense? Why do you use an enum? Use raw bit-fiels such as `uint8_t` then mask them with bitwise operators. And what makes you think that another sensor will have an internal memory map in the same manner? That's highly unlikely - you can be happy if it even follows the same SPI settings, since SPI is poorly standardized. Also, there's no guarantee of endianess in the sensor registers etc. There's no such thing as a "portable driver", if you change the sensor you must rewrite the driver.

Comment: I use an enum to be able to call each field (e.g., X1) by a unique name.
Thanks for your comment

Comment: And why cant do you do `field[0] & X1` where X1 is the unique bit mask?

Comment: Well, I just didn't have this idea beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in essence "no" since it comes down to the particular register layout of the sensor in question. These are, as far as I know, never self-describing so you're going to have to statically "know" in the software end what is available and where.

Of course what you can do if you're desperate is to invent (or find) a DSL that is better at describing arbitrary bit fields than C, and describe the register set in that. Then use code generation techniques to make the required C code, thus moving the part that needs to be updated into a more suitable language (at the cost of more actual software *complexity*, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I prefer longer but easier work compared to more complex work. I'll keep doing it the in the same current way